# How to perform grep on 'man unix_command'?

Tags: shell, grep, man

Often while going through the output of man

```
man awk
```

I Need to perform grep, for e.g. in man awk, I need to find the definition of a particular flag, variable etc. Can anyone tell me, what would be corresponding the grep command, or is there is a better way to do it.
I tried this command, but it is eating all the new lines

```
echo `man awk`| grep NR
```

Comment: Why plain simple `man awk | grep NR` doesn't work?

Comment: Or just `man awk | less +/NR`.  You can also search for the N-th occurrence, with something like this: `man awk | less +2/NR`.

Comment: For such tasks, I usually just open it in vim `man awk | vim -`. In vim, I can then do anything.

Answer (score 5):

You can just use `grep` as a pager:

```
man -P 'grep NR' awk
```

but it is way better to just search for pattern with `/` in `less` (that is probably your default pager), so:

```
man awk
```

and then

```
/^ *NR
```

This way you will find only headers (patterns at the beginning of the lines).

Answer (score 3):

With the command you tried, `echo` is printing every word in the manual page on a single line.

You would have had a better luck with:

```
echo "`man awk`" | grep NR
```

or better

```
echo "$(man awk)" | grep NR
```

or even better, given the fact `echo` is useless here:

```
man awk | grep NR
```

Note that most if not all `man` implementations detect their output is a pipe and remove terminal specific formatting in that case.

With some Unix, `man` outputs some information during its work (eg: Solaris `man` says "*Reformatting page.  Please Wait... done*"), this can be skipped from the output that way:

```
man awk 2>/dev/null | grep NR
```

Comment: How could one intentionally keep `man`'s formatting within a pipe?

Comment: @JonathanWheeler This might work: `zless $(man -w awk) | nroff -man `